# Why does convolution over a 5x5 image with a 2x2 filter produce 32 features in TF MNIST?

Tags: tensorflow

I don't understand why in the [official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/mnist/pros/index.html#first-convolutional-layer) the convolution of a 5x5 patch with a 2x2 filter produces 32 features...

The convolution is shifted by 1 each time so it should produce 6*6 = 36 features, not 32. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: 32 is the number of channels not the number of features

Comment: it says "The convolutional will compute 32 features for each 5x5 patch."

Comment: Sorry I thought you were getting the 32 from the code 'W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32])'. I don't see how it could generate 32 features as new "pixels" because the square root of 32 isn't an integer and the image is a square.

Comment: so you mean there is an issue in the official tutorial ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

32 is a hyper-parameter: once you define the network you choose how many features to extract from the input.

With an input of 28x28x1, you choose to learn 32 convolutional filters.
A learned convolutional filter extracts a single feature.

```
W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32])
```

... is the definition of a set of 32 filters each of size 5x5x1 that the network will learn after the training phase.

You can change the number of convolutional filters to learn since it is a hyper-parameter, so it's totally arbitrary.

For example, you can choose to extract 64 features from the first convolutional layer, by changing the previous line as follows:

```
W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 64])
b_conv1 = bias_variable([64]) #change biases as well
```

But you have to keep track of this change in the following layer.

In the tutorial you find the definition of another set of convolutional filters:

```
W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64])
```

This is the definition of a set of 64 convolutional filters each of size 5x5x32.

If you change the first layer in order to extract 64 features, you have to change this layer accordingly:

```
    W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 64, 64])
```

This means that each one of the 64 extracted features is combined with another 64 features: the abstraction increases.

The first layers extract simple features (edges, lines, ...), the other layers combine the extracted features to form more complex features.

> The convolution is shifted by 1 each time so it should produce 6*6 = 36 features, not 32.

The "shift" (it's called stride, `S`) is the number of pixels to jump when performing a 2d convolution.

If the input has a side of 28 px, the output of a convolution with a (set of) filter(s) of side 5 is `(28 - 5 + 2P)/S=1 + 1 = 24`

Since the convolution op has the padding argument=SAME, the value of `P` is calculated in order to produce an output with the same size as the input, thus 28.

Your 6*6 has no meaning.

## Long story short:

Do not confuse the number of features extracted (a hyper-parameter) with the size of the activation map. The activation map is the result of the convolution between the input and the learned convolutional filters (also called kernels).

Comment: This is a perfect explanation actually, one thing left is how did you get this equation: (28 - 5 + 2P)/S=1 + 1 = 24 ?

Comment: Another question is, padding = SAME... does this means that the filter of 5x5 shall not get outside the boundary of the image ? if so then it shall be 28-4 not 28-5 .. I dont still get the /S = 1 + 1 = 24 part ...

Comment: That part maybe is a bit confused. I try to make it clear. The formula to calculate the side of the output is: (Input_side - kernel_side +2 Padding)/Stride + 1. This formula, actually, is well known in the computer vision field. You can convince yourself that the calculated value is correct, just try it out. If the value is not integer, the stride value is wrong (other hyperparameter, and you have to change it). Padding=same means: input side = output side. So it calculates the valid value for the P (Padding parameter) to make the equation true

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says:

> The convolutional will compute 32 features for each 5x5 patch. Its weight tensor will have a shape of [5, 5, 1, 32]

Your confusion arises because you think that 32 features represents the number of parameters the output of a convolution will have. But this is not the case.

[tf.nn.conv2d()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d) says that the second parameter represents your filter and consists of `[filter_height, filter_width, in_channels, out_channels]`. So `[5, 5, 1, 32]` means that your `in_channels` is 1: you have a greyscale image, so no surprises here.

32 means that during our learning phase, the network will try to learn 32 different kernels which will be used during the prediction. You can change this number to any other number as it is a hyperparameter that you can tune.